# Помогите сделать горизонтальную прокрутку блоков по кнопке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

В целом на страницу должны выводиться ***5 блоков***, остальные должны продвигаться
***по 1 - смещение на 210px ***

Я видел варианты решения на `js`, но у меня возникли проблемы именно с `css` они уползают в вторую строку

```css
body {
  background: #4d5b6f;
}

.hg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

.ff {
  width: 1050px;
  height: 210px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<div class="ff">
  <div class="hg"></div>
  <div class="hg"></div>
  <div class="hg"></div>
  <div class="hg"></div>
  <div class="hg"></div>
  <div class="hg"></div>
  <div class="hg"></div>
</div>
<div id="+1">вперед</div>
<div id="-1">назад</div>
```

Comment: а что не так? тут все блоки в одну строку

Comment: Блоков показывает 5, а их 7, надо  чтоб через горизонтальную полосу прокрутки можно было все 7 увидеть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще свой вариант с `flex` предложу:

```js
var totalWidth = 0;

$('.slider-item').each(function(index) {
    totalWidth += parseInt($(this).outerWidth(true), 10);
});

$('.slider-win').width(totalWidth);

$('#sl-next').on('click', function(){
  
  
  var $this = $(this),
      $slider = $this.closest('.slider'),
      $sliderWin = $slider.find('.slider-win'),
      item = $sliderWin.find('.slider-item'),
      pos = item.outerWidth(true); 
  
  
  if($sliderWin.css('margin-left') <= '-1200px'){
    $sliderWin.animate(
      {'margin-left': '0px'}, 
      1000
    ); 
  } else {
    $sliderWin.animate(
      {'margin-left': '-='+pos}, 
      1000
    ); 
  }
  
  
});

$('#sl-prev').on('click', function(){
  
  
  var $this = $(this),
      $slider = $this.closest('.slider'),
      $sliderWin = $slider.find('.slider-win'),
      item = $sliderWin.find('.slider-item'),
      pos = item.outerWidth(true),
      posX = $sliderWin.offset().left; 
    
    if(posX <= 0){
      $sliderWin.animate(
        {'margin-left': '+='+pos}, 
        1000
      );  
    } else {
      $sliderWin.animate(
        {'margin-left': '0px'},  
        1000
      ); 
    }
    
  
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #4d5b6f;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.slider {
  max-width: 425px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color:#fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
  background: orangered;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink:0;
}

.slider-win {  
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  /* overflow-x: scroll; */
}

.slider-control {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.sl-btn {
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius:5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sl-btn:hover {
  opacity: .85;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>


<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-win">
    <div class="slider-item">1</div>
    <div class="slider-item">2</div>
    <div class="slider-item">3</div>
    <div class="slider-item">4</div>
    <div class="slider-item">5</div>
    <div class="slider-item">6</div>
    <div class="slider-item">7</div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-control">
    <div id="sl-prev" class="sl-btn">назад</div>
    <div id="sl-next" class="sl-btn">вперед</div>      
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое

Answer (score 4):

Смысл такой. В данном примере что бы блоки выравнивались по горизонтальной оси реализовано на `flex-ах`. Но, что бы появлялась полоса прокрутки сами блоки не должны иметь ширину, так как на них воздействует непосредственный контейнер
 ***(родитель)***. Чтобы задать высоту и ширину блоку `.hg` в него следует сунуть блок с требуемой шириной и высотой

```css
body {
  background: #4d5b6f;
}

.ff {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: blue;
}

.hg {
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}
.inner-block{
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ff">
  <div class="hg"><div class="inner-block"></div></div>
  <div class="hg"><div class="inner-block"></div></div>
  <div class="hg"><div class="inner-block"></div></div>
  <div class="hg"><div class="inner-block"></div></div>
  <div class="hg"><div class="inner-block"></div></div>
  <div class="hg"><div class="inner-block"></div></div>
  <div class="hg"><div class="inner-block"></div></div>
  
</div>
<div class="btn" id="prev">вперед</div>
<div class="btn" id="next">назад</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Выше уже дали правильный ответ, но если нужно конкретно на Вашем примере:

```css
body {
  background: #4d5b6f;
}

.hg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ff {
  width: 1050px;
  height: 210px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<div class="ff">
  <div class="hg"></div>
  <div class="hg"></div>
  <div class="hg"></div>
  <div class="hg"></div>
  <div class="hg"></div>
  <div class="hg"></div>
  <div class="hg"></div>
</div>
<div id="+1">вперед</div>
<div id="-1">назад</div>
```

Comment: funforlifefix, не переживай даже если дали ответ, любой ответ полезен и интересен...  держи плюс

Answer (score 1):

А лучше всего вот так:

```js
let hg = document.getElementsByClassName('hg');
console.log(hg)
let move = 0;
function plus(){
    move -= 210;
    hg[0].style.marginLeft = move + 'px';  
}
function minus(){
    move += 210;
    hg[0].style.marginLeft = move + 'px';

}
```

```css
.ff{
  width:1080px;
  height:210px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ff .hg{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:10px;
  background-size: cover; 
  background:red;
  margin:5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#plus,#minus {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="ff">
  <div class="hg">1</div>
  <div class="hg">2</div>
  <div class="hg">3</div>
  <div class="hg">4</div>
  <div class="hg">5</div>
  <div class="hg">6</div>
  <div class="hg">7</div>
</div>
<div id="plus" onclick="plus()">вперед</div>
<div id="minus" onclick="minus()">назад</div>
```